# Android button first and second click

Tags: android

I need help with button first and second click. first click should send an sms and changing button background color and button text color. Second click should send an other sms and set back button backcolor and text color. thanks.

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            sendSMSMessage1();

            // On second click do other event 

            sendSMSMessage11();
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            sendSMSMessage2();
            // On second click do other event

            sendSMSMessage22();

            btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="123dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="372dp"
    android:text="START"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.521"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:strokeColor="#ffffff"
    app:strokeWidth="5dp" />
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?? Please add the xml code for your buttons

Comment: I need the button to act twice, I mean first click do somthing and click second time do other thing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via additional flag. For example

```
boolean wasButtonClicked = false;

button.setOnLongClickListener {
  if (wasButtonClicked) {
    //action 2
  } else {
    //action1
  }
}
```

Comment: how to add it in my code and keep the structure of my code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

this way did not work.

```
        case R.id.button1:
            boolean wasButtonClicked = false;
            if (wasButtonClicked) {
                btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                btn1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                sendSMSMessage1();
            }
            else {
                btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: make variable `boolean wasButtonClicked = false;` class-global, move it out of case branch

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet:

```
boolean buttonClicked = false; //click track for button 1
boolean buttonClicked2 = false; //click track for button 2

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
            if(buttonClicked){
              btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
              btn1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
              sendSMSMessage1();
            }else{
              sendSMSMessage11();
              btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
              btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            break;
          case R.id.button2:
            buttonClicked2 = !buttonClicked2;
            //do similar stuff
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

also in your xml of your button you may need to add onClick attribute so that it handles your onClick if you have not done by your java code.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="123dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="372dp"
    android:text="START"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.521"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:strokeColor="#ffffff"
    //add your onClick android:onClick="onLongClick" //or app:onClick = "onLongClick"  
//one should work as you have mentioned on click not long click in your question
    app:strokeWidth="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

worked like charm, many thanks all:

boolean buttonClicked = false; //click track for button 1
boolean buttonClicked2 = false; //click track for button 2

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

```
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
        if(buttonClicked){
          btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
          btn1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
          sendSMSMessage1();
        }else{
          sendSMSMessage11();
          btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
          btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        break;
      case R.id.button2:
        buttonClicked2 = !buttonClicked2;
        //do similar stuff
        break;
}
return true;
```

}